# What is the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() equivalent for OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, core-graphics

Title says it all.

I'm trying to figure out what the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` equivalent is for OS X.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I might have been going a bit too hard on my quest to find falsely tagged questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`[NSGraphicsContext currentContext].CGContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/index.html).

(The `-CGContext` property is available in 10.10 and later; in earlier versions, you can use `graphicsPort`.)

Comment: Wow. That was easy.. Thanks!

Comment: Things were pretty rough on OS X till 10.10 :-)

Answer (score 4):

For Swift:
`NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext`

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, in Swift 4, the syntax is:

```
NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
```